# start time in openssl s_client

Tags: ssl, openssl, time, curl

After running the openssl s_client command to connect to a remote host. The following output was shown on the terminal. Can somebody please help me understand the `start time` in this log. What does it represent and what format is it in ?

I believe it should be wall clock time and in microseconds. However I have not been able to find documentation related to it.

```
   ---
SSL handshake has read 3876 bytes and written 319 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 3F4EE3992B46727BE2C7C3E76A9A6A8D64D66EE843CB1BB17A76AE2E030C7161
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 016209E50432EFE2359DB73AB527AF718152BFE6F88215A9CE40604E8FF2E2A3AC97A175F46DF737596866A8BC8E3F7F
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1397678467
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
DONE
```

Also is there any way to just measure the handshake time and the time to complete a request (record phase of tls) using openssl s_client or s_time.

s_time represents the overall time taken for a handshake and time to get the resource from the server.

Using curl, there may be a way to get *time_appconnect* which is handshake timing, *time_total* and then subtract the both to get an approximate timing for the record phase.  (ignoring the time taken to do a lookup, requests etc as they are really negligible).

I am trying to measure the time taken to establish a TLS connection with some firewall rules and without some firewall rules.

Comment: Is your computer's clock set correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is. !!. The output is the same format on two computers.

Answer (score 1):

About the Start Time it's a time stamp you can get it through a date or convert it through it.

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date "+%s") #timestamp
starttime="1397678467"
convert=$(date --date="@$starttime" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
echo $convert
```

So your time stamp when converted you will get this date 2014-04-16 23:01:07

---

Also you can use the date command to help you convert and calculate  time_appconnect and time_total that came from curl -w output

Try dividing time_appconnect or time_total  / 60 = minutes. as the time_total  or time_appconnect will be printed in seconds

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I am not sure if this would be enough to calculate the handhsake time effectively as the start time is not in precision compared to the date command.

Comment: Also known as UNIX time, or elapsed seconds since the epoch.